# How can I learn about the state of activity without overriding related functions?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there a way to learn about the state of activity without overriding `onPause`, `onResume`, etc?

Comment: Why do you want to know?  There may be a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have no ability to override this functions because activity is generated automatically. I want to knaw how I can get its state (maybe from Android system).

Comment: Generated automatically where?

Comment: It is an AIR android program. It generates blank activity where Flash runs. I know that AIR have its own methods to get application state but they do not work properly.

Comment: So, why do you want to know the state of AIR's activity?  What did you try with regard to using the built-in AIR methods that failed?  How did they "not work properly"?  That sounds like your real issue.

Comment: As the APK is ultimately under your control, you could modify it after the tools are done with it, but that seems inefficient compared to figuring out how they want you to do things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found answer.
It's about home button but works fine with detecting app state (is it in background or not):
http://tutorials-android.blogspot.com/2013/08/detect-home-button-press-in-android-and.html

Comment: This will not be a workable answer in practice, as the button is by no means the only reason your app could cease to be in the foreground.

Comment: If you read article carefully you can notice that it is about checking is app in the top of running tasks.

Comment: No, it's not.  Nor even if it were would that be sufficient or reliable.

Comment: Sure, in the trivial cases you think to test with now.  You'll find in actual use that it doesn't.